# Retrieve Firebase images as drawables and display in recycler View

Tags: java, android, firebase

i have implemented RecyclerView that displays images succesfully and everthing is working fine
now in my Frgament i want to load the images from Firebase (images already stored on Realtime Database with their urls)
this is my Fragment Code

```
public RecyclerView youthRecycler;
public RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerAdapter;
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerManager;


//i just want to populate this array with drawables from images stored on firebase
int[] imagesArray={R.drawable.youthtable1,R.drawable.youthtable2,R.drawable.youthtable3};

public tableYouthFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_table_youth, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //all code goes here
    init();
}
public void init()
{
    youthRecycler=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.youthRecycler);
    youthRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    youthRecycler.setLayoutManager(recyclerManager);
    recyclerAdapter =new MyRecyclerAdpater(getActivity(),imagesArray);
    youthRecycler.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
}
```

this question is already asked here but without any verified answers, and the verified answers where in kotlin and the java answers required that i change my RecyclerView whole Implementation . i followed up many tutorials on glide library also but didn't know if it's even possible to load the images as drawables or i must change my whole adapter implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recyclerView should take a list of url's and u can load them in Glide why u need to load them as drawable and glide can load them as url:

in onBindViewHolder():

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).into(holder.imageYouWantToShow);
```

now in the fragment get the urls:

```
 DatabaseRefernce imagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 ValueEventListener imagesListner = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot imageUrl: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           String image = imageUrl.getValue(String.class);
           imagesArray.add(image);
      }
  
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }
};
imagesRef.addValueEventListener(imagesListner );

recyclerManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
youthRecycler.setLayoutManager(recyclerManager);
recyclerAdapter = new MyRecyclerAdpater(this,imagesArray);
youthRecycler.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: that worked great , i had a misconception on how the glide worked , didn't know it could immediately load the image from the url. Thank You